# Scale Axis Markers in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following graph where I'm trying to scale the display of the result for the axis labeled "Pressure."  I would like the result to show "2,000" instead of "2".

[image]

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[letterpage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                view={60}{30},
                axis equal image,
                width=\textwidth,
                xlabel style={align=center},
                xlabel={Pressure \\ $q_v$},
                ylabel={$y$},
                zlabel={$z$}
                ]
                \addplot3[
                patch,
                fill=white,
                opacity=0.8,
                samples=51,
                domain=-3:3,
                y domain=0:-3,
                point meta=x
                ]
                ({-3*5*5^2*y/(2*3.1415*(1.5^2+x^2+y^2)^2.5)}, x, y);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just add `xtick={0,2},xticklabels={$0$,{$2,000$}},` to the options of your axis.

Comment: @marmot, suppose that these values could change, I would be looking for a solution where they would update automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, how about

```
\documentclass[letterpage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={grays}{gray(0cm)=(0.5);gray(1cm)=(0)}}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                view={60}{30},
                axis equal image,
                width=\textwidth,
                xlabel style={align=center},
                xlabel={Pressure \\ $q_v$},
                ylabel={$y$},
                zlabel={$z$},
                %xtick={0,2},
                xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{1000*\tick}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$},
                ]
                \addplot3[
                patch,
                fill=white,
                opacity=0.8,
                samples=51,
                domain=-3:3,
                y domain=0:-3,
                point meta=x
                ]
                ({-3*5*5^2*y/(2*3.1415*(1.5^2+x^2+y^2)^2.5)}, x, y);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

then?

[image]